Expresión regular para etiquetas (hashtags)
Estoy aprendiendo dart. Necesito una expresión regular que detecte etiquetas (hashtags); explico:
necesito que se puedan aceptar las siguientes cadenas:

#estasi
#esta #si
#esta no
#esta#no
estano

La expresión que tengo es la siguiente:
RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^#(?:\S+|#\S+)*$');

pero no me da el resultado esperado.

RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^#\S+(?:\s*#\S+)*$');
Termine usando este regex, y cumple con los requerimientos solicitados, gracias a todos

Prueba con esta expresion
RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^#(\S+\s?)*$');
^: indica el inicio de la cadena.
#: indica que debe comenzar con #.
(\S+\s?)*: un grupo que busca uno o más caracteres no vacíos (\S+), seguido opcionalmente por un espacio (\s?). El * al final del grupo permite repetir este patrón, por lo que acepta cadenas como #algo #algo.

Intenta aplicar la siguiente expresión:
RegExp(r'\B#\w+\b')

Te pongo un ejemplo a continuación:
String value = "#Hola #Mundo"; //output: [#Hola, #Mundo]
String value2 = "#Hola#Mundo"; //output: [#Hola]
String value3 = "Hola"; //output: []

RegExp exp = RegExp(r'\B#\w+\b');

Iterable<Match> matches = exp.allMathches(value); //puede ser value o value2
List<String?> hashtags = matches.map((e) => e.group(0)).tolist();

print(hashtags);

Si deseas que cuando haya dos etiquetas juntas sin un espacio en medio no te detecte ninguna entonces agregale esto a la expresión regular: (?!#):
RegExp(r'\B#\w+\b(?!#)')

Te explico para que sirve cada uno:

\B: Usamos para buscar una posición que no esté al principio ni final de una palabra.
#: Busca el hashtag.
\w+: Busca todo caracter alfanumérico o guiones bajos en la etiqueta.
\b: Determina el límite de la palabra, impidiendo que incluya cualquier otro caracter.
(?!#): Es un lookahead negativo, nos ayuda a verificar que la coincidencia actual no esté seguido de otro "#".

Espero mi respuesta te haya sido útil.
